# How to assign value from one column to another column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables A and B I am using left join and query returns two columns phone, cid Like this

```
select B.phone
     , A.cid 
  from B 
  left 
  join A 
    on A.id_cc_card = cc_card.id 
 where A.cid is null


phone     cid 
5656565   null
4546565   null
```

Now my problem is I want to assign value of phone to cid using mysql like this

```
   phone    cid
  5656565   5656565 
  4546565   4546565
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See COALESCE().

Comment: Why asking the same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629692/how-to-update-value-from-one-column-to-another-in-left-join-query-result/46629811#46629811

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you will get your desired result which mentioned in you question.

```
select B.phone,B.phone as cid from B left join A on 
A.id_cc_card=cc_card.id where A.cid is null
```

Comment: I want to assign values from phone column to cid column.